# Protocol "curl https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: php, curl, https, xampp

Hi I'm using XAMPP Version v3.2.2 and I've tried to use an API with the PHP CURL Lib. But on every request I get this Error Message:

> Protocol "curl https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

```
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_URL => 'curl https://dawanda.com/[XYZ]/products?v=1.1',
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('X-Dawanda-Auth: [XYZ]')
  ));
  $resp = curl_exec($curl);

  echo curl_error($curl);

  curl_close($curl);
```

[image: Those are my CURL properties]

I don't understand the error message, because the https-protocol is listed in the phpinfo().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the 'curl ' in the url  CURLOPT_URL => 'curl https://dawanda.com/[XYZ]/products?v=1.1' so that

```
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_URL => 'https://dawanda.com/[XYZ]/products?v=1.1',
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('X-Dawanda-Auth: [XYZ]'),
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
  ));
  $resp = curl_exec($curl);

  echo curl_error($curl);

  curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Well then i get this error message: **SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**

Comment: I've updated my answer and added these lines   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false).

Comment: You just need to be aware of the fact that you are now vulnerable to MITM attacks due to not knowing who you talk to. Switching off the verification is not recommended for more than testing.